# How can I call a numpy ufunc with two positional arguments in polars?

Tags: python-polars

I would like to call a numpy universal function (ufunc) that has two positional arguments in polars.

```py
df.with_column(
    numpy.left_shift(pl.col('col1'), 8)
)
```

Above attempt results in the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/polars/internals/expr.py", line 181, in __array_ufunc__
    out_type = ufunc(np.array([1])).dtype
TypeError: left_shift() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 1 were given
```

There are other ways to perform this computation, e.g.,

```
df['col1'] = numpy.left_shift(df['col1'], 8)
```

... but I'm trying to use this with a `polars.LazyFrame`.

I'm using polars 0.13.13 and Python 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: as of Polars `0.13.19`, the `apply` method converts Numpy datatypes to Polars datatypes without requiring the Numpy `item` method.

When you need to pass only one column from polars to the ufunc (as in your example), the easist method is to use the `apply` function on the particular column.

```py
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [2, 4, 8, 16]}).lazy()

df.with_column(
    pl.col("col1").apply(lambda x: np.left_shift(x, 8).item()).alias("result")
).collect()
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬────────┐
│ col1 ┆ result │
│ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪════════╡
│ 2    ┆ 512    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 1024   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8    ┆ 2048   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16   ┆ 4096   │
└──────┴────────┘
```

If you need to pass multiple columns from Polars to the ufunc, then use the `struct` expression with `apply`.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1": [2, 4, 8, 16], "shift": [1, 1, 2, 2]}).lazy()

df.with_column(
    pl.struct(["col1", "shift"])
    .apply(lambda cols: np.left_shift(cols["col1"], cols["shift"]).item())
    .alias("result")
).collect()
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬────────┐
│ col1 ┆ shift ┆ result │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ i64    │
╞══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 2    ┆ 1     ┆ 4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4    ┆ 1     ┆ 8      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8    ┆ 2     ┆ 32     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 16   ┆ 2     ┆ 64     │
└──────┴───────┴────────┘
```

One Note: the use of the numpy `item` method may no longer be needed in future releases of Polars.  (Presently, the `apply` method does not always automatically translate between numpy dtypes and Polars dtypes.)

Does this help?